# How can the Describe for a Field of getPopulatedFieldsAsMap() be null

Tags: null-pointer, describefieldresult, crud, guest-user

I'm doing a CR**U**D check on Field level, since under some weird circumstances our customers don't have update rights on Record level, but only on fields (it's a guest license). So in addition to the [fflib_SObjectDomain](https://github.com/financialforcedev/fflib-apex-common/blob/master/fflib/src/classes/fflib_SObjectDomain.cls#L217) CRUD check on Record level, we had to implement an additional check on field level. It worked, but it's still failing in a view cases with a null pointer in this line:

```
&& !field.getDescribe().isUpdateable()
```

but I have no idea how the field or it's describe could be null. Anyone out there any idea? Additional info: there are different record types.

```
Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> allFields = records.getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap();    

for(SObject record : records) {
    Map<String, Object> recordFields = record.getPopulatedFieldsAsMap();
    for(String fieldName : recordFields.keySet()) {
        Schema.SObjectField field = allFields.get(fieldName);

        if(record.get(field) != oldRecords.get(record.Id).get(field)
                && !field.getDescribe().isUpdateable()) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Weird. Is `field` null or `field.getDescribe()` null? Suggest you `System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(allFields))` and `System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(recordFields))` if `field` is null to see what is going on.

Comment: Hm It's a customers org and we had no option to reproduce it since we don't have access to guest licenses :( But I'll put this into the next patch and disable crud for now. Thanks for the serialize pretty hint, never used that :)

Comment: hmm upload failed: Apex Type unsupported in JSON: Schema.SObjectField

Comment: Sorry didn't realise that. I guess it will have to be `System.debug(JSON.serializePretty(allFields.keySet()))` and also `System.debug('fieldName=' + fieldName + ' field=' + field)`.